# How to pass variable in register of react-hook-form 7

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

Since v 7, react-hook-forms have stopped using refs. I have been trying to make my form dynamic, taking field props from a json file, but the register of useForm gives me a type issue everytime.

```
const {register , and so on..}= useForm({defaultvalues : {A:a,B:b, and so on..}})
...
{fields.map(f,i)=>
<TextField id={f.id} ..and so on.. 
{...register(`${f.id}` as const)} //error
/>}
```

The error being :

```
type string is not assignable to parameter of type '"A"|"B"| and so on'. ts2345
```

f.id returns the same values they want over there, yet i cant solve this.

Comment: I have ommited unnecessary syntax. Please dont worry about brackets and other syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the type that the react-hook-form provides instead of `as const`.

**before "react-hook-form": "^7.41.0"**

```js
const name = `car.seat${index}.color`;

// omitted the other parts
{...register(name as Path<FormInputs>)}
```

**as of "react-hook-form": "^7.41.0"**

```js
const name = `car.seat${index}.color`;

// omitted the other parts
{...register(name as Path<UnPackAsyncDefaultValues<FormInputs>>)}
```

Of course, **the *register* function type** is with the generic type `UseFormRegister<FormInputs>` that you defined for the form, for example:

````
type FormInputs = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
};
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try building the same structure for your register name as in your object.
For example if you have this object:

```
{
   "car":[
      {
         "seat0":"color"
      },
      {
         "seat1":"color"
      }
   ]
}
```

Then if you want to map trough this and build your table, just do something like this.

```
{ data.map((item, index) => { 
              return (<TextField id={index} ..and so on.. 
              {...register(`car.seat${index}.color`)} />);
          }) }
```